# ati graphics card

Tags: ati

I just installed ubuntu 12.10 and I want to use ATI's driver because my computer is getting hot but I'm afraid to install cause I've tried to install before and I had serious problem.
My graphics card model ATI 6520G.I don't know what will ı do I hope you can help me

Comment: I sorted out to problem updated kernel to 3.5.0.21 and I'm using fglrx-updates ıt's working fine rıght now

Comment: Please write this solution as answer and close this question. Thank you!